# How to get a summary of commits in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I would like to get a summary of commits with the following information

- Number of days worked, start day & end day.
- Activity summary by day - just number of commits & number of lines changed.

Is there an extension which does this ?

Comment: start day and end day of what?

Comment: But anyway - everything you ask can be done easily manually

Comment: start day is day of first commit. end day is the day of last commit. Number of days worked: number of days with non-zero number of commits.

Comment: I hardly doubt there might be an extension that does such a specific job, but as I said - it's pretty trivial to implement it yourself

Answer (score 9):

`hg help log` + `hg help diff` + `hg help revsets` + `hg help templating` `hg help dates` + bash

- Date of first commit|last commit

Initial commit always has rev 0, latest is always tip

`hg log -r 0 --template "{date|date}\n"`

`hg log -r tip --template "{date|date}\n"`

- Number of days worked: number of days with non-zero number of commits

`hg log --template "{date(date,'%d%m%y')}\n" | sort -u | wc -l`

- Activity summary by day - just number of commits

`hg log -r "date('YYYY-MM-DD')" --template "{.}\n" | wc -l`

number of lines changed (first ugly draft iteration: "feci quod potui, faciant meliora potentes")

`hg diff --stat -r "first(date('YYYY-MM-DD'))" -r "last(date('YYYY-MM-DD'))"`

Sample output of such diff

```
 404.php        |    4 +-
 comments.php   |   14 +-----
 footer.php     |    2 +-
 functions.php  |   24 +++++++++-
 header.php     |    2 +-
 readme.txt     |   38 +++++++++++++++++
 screenshot.png |  Bin
 search.php     |   12 +++-
 sidebar.php    |   45 ++------------------
 style.css      |  121 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++----------------------------
 10 files changed, 139 insertions(+), 123 deletions(-)
```

**Note:** YYYY-MM-DD is placeholder, you have to write real datein this format into command

**Note 2:** Less than hour for preparing and testing results!!!

Comment: I think your answer covers the vast majority of practical cases, but I want to point out that the tipmost changeset isn't necessarily the one that was committed most recently - it's the one that was added to the current clone most recently. I can commit something today, then pull a changeset of yours from three months ago, and your changeset (with its commit date of three months ago) will be tip *in my clone*. Of course, if I do something like merge your change, I'd create a new (and recent) tip.

Comment: @shambulator - OK, most recent by timestamp can be `hg log -r "last(sort(all(),date))"`

Answer (score 8):

[LazyBadger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16209901/351301) gives you a way to find out the dates of first and last commits. For a breakdown of number of daily changesets committed and lines of code changed, enable the [churn extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ChurnExtension) that ships with Mercurial. In either global or repository config:

```
[extensions]
churn=
```

Then for a breakdown of number of *changesets* by day, in chronological order:

```
$ hg churn --template "{date|shortdate}" --sort --changesets
```

or for lines of code:

```
$ hg churn --template "{date|shortdate}" --sort
```

with optional `diffstat` to show added/removed lines separately:

```
$ hg churn --template "{date|shortdate}" --sort --diffstat
```

Check `hg help churn` for more options, like limiting range of dates or changesets considered.